# Hangout chat bot private distribution

Tags: google-hangouts

After developing the [Hangout chat bot](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop) I could see the steps to [publish](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-publish) and distribute by [listing on marketplace](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/gsm-list)

I'm wondering if there's a way to distribute the bot privately to other gsuite domains without actually creating the bot and configure it in that domain's cloud console?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge through the API configuration this is not possible without setting it up in your own domain. If you try and connect to a Google script outside of your domain, it will give you a domain error. (see fake example below)

You also cannot add specific users outside of your domain to have access to the bot.

However, if you want your bot to be public for everyone please see here: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/gsm-list

But referencing another bot in another domain does not seem to be possible otherwise.

[image]